# Relative Record Separator in Perl

Tags: perl, parsing, data-structures

I have a data that looks like this:

```
id:40108689 --
chr22_scrambled_bysegments:10762459:F : chr22:17852459:F (1.0),
id:40108116 --
chr22_scrambled_bysegments:25375481:F : chr22_scrambled_bysegments:25375481:F (1.0),
chr22_scrambled_bysegments:25375481:F : chr22:19380919:F (1.0),
id:1 --
chr22:21133765:F : chr22:21133765:F (0.0),
```

So each record is separated by `id:[somenumber] --`

What's the way to access the data so that we can have a hash of array:

```
$VAR = { 'id:40108689' => [' chr22_scrambled_bysegments:10762459:F : chr22:17852459:F (1.0),'], 

         'id:40108116' => ['chr22_scrambled_bysegments:25375481:F :chr22_scrambled_bysegments:25375481:F (1.0)',
'chr22_scrambled_bysegments:25375481:F : chr22:19380919:F (1.0),'
         #...etc
       }
```

I tried to approach this using record separator. But not sure how to generalize it?

```
{
    local $/ = " --\n";  # How to include variable content id:[number] ?

    while ($content = <INFILE>) {
      chomp $content;
      print "$content\n" if $content; # Skip empty records
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my $result = {};
my $last_id;
while (my $line = <INFILE>) {
    if ($line =~ /(id:\d+) --/) {
        $last_id = $1;
        next;
    }
    next unless $last_id; # Just in case the file doesn't start with an id line

    push @{ $result->{$last_id} }, $line;
} 

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $result;
```

Uses the normal record separator.

Uses $last_id to keep track of the last id row encountered and is set to the next id when another one is encountered. Pushes non-id rows on to an array for the hash key of the last matched id line.

Comment: Thanks. But, I think you need this minor correction: `if ( $line !~ /id:\d+ --/ ) {
        push @{ $result->{$last_id} }, $line;

        }
`